# iOS: distribute app for enterprise customer's employees

Tags: ios, enterprise, itunes-store, b2b

We're developing an app for an enterprise customer (approx. 1500 of its users are going to use it). At the moment the most likely way we're going to charge them is on a per-usage basis (every time an employee uses the app, we get a small amount), so it's important that the app is distributed only among employees.  I'm considering using iOS Developer Enterprise Program ( https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ ) or releasing an app via a regular iTunes Store with some basic marketing functionality and then letting users to log in and use the real functionality the customer is paying for. 
Edit: perhaps the B2B Volume Purchase Program ( https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/ ) is the answer?

- Are there any other possibilities?
- What's the most convenient way of distributing such app?
- If I go with iOS Dev Enterprise Program, who should create the account? Us or them? (I'm betting the latter).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your per-usage model is against Apple's Ts&Cs in any deployment space (B2B, App Store, etc). I'm also fairly confident that deploying through the App Store will get you flagged eventually when they dive into your code. Either of those deployment models is going to get you shut down and your Enterprise Cert revoked if they ever catch on. Either way you likely want to have someone fluent with legalese look at what you're attempting to do.

The point of using B2B to circumvent the App Store is to allow you to provide a private deployment of an app at a minimal cost without supplying source code. To that point the customer should be the one maintaining the Enterprise account. You would join their account as a Member, compile the code using one of their dev certs and dev provisioning profiles, supply the customer with the .XCArchive file and they can re-sign it with their Enterprise Cert. It's a pretty streamlined process.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Developer program is convenient because you don't need to go through the store review process.  Just put up new builds for installation from your own www site.  The enterprise whose employees will be using the app needs to get the license.  They will need a DUNS number and the application process may take a week or so.  They may get a phone call from Apple to verify their intentions and eligibility.